# Why can't I move just my text files to different folder in Python?

Tags: python, shell, module, shutil

I am using the Python shutil module to move 4 txt files from FolderA to FolderB.

When I run the following code I get a trace-back error:

```
shutil.move('C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderA.txt', 'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderB')
```

But I know that pathway does in fact exist because when I try this command it works fine and moves the whole Folder A(including txt files) into FolderB:

```
shutil.move('C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderA', 'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderB')
```

Any way to move just the text files without just copying them? I am using Python Shell 2.7 in case you wanted to know.

Comment: What is the traceback error? Why do you think `FolderA.txt` equals the 4 text files? You may want to look into the `fnmatch` or the `glob` modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, escape the path separator correctly, either use double backslash or add a `r''` in front to indicate its raw string like below

this command is not doing what you intended, it try to move file call FolderA.txt into FolderB

```
shutil.move(r'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderA.txt', r'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderB')
```

code below should do what you intended. 
Use glob module to grep all txt file in FolderA then move them 1 by 1 into FolderB

```
import glob
# this will move all txt file from FolderA into FolderB
# but you need to ensure FolderB exists, else it might create a file named FolderB instead
for f in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderA\*.txt'):
    shutil.move(f, r'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderB')
```

Comment: Is it possible to just use the shutil module?

Comment: This has been what I've been instructed to use.

Comment: i have no idea if thats possible, at most you could use os.listdir() to get all the file list instead of using glob module, if you wanna move everything in folder without filtering .txt file then its doable with shutil alone

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double backslashes when using Windows paths, otherwise the next character is escaped and thus raises the `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:...'`. I.e.

```
shutil.move('C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\FolderA.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\FolderB')
```

Comment: I should of noted that double backslashes still gave me the same error.